# Accessing a text file with a variable

Tags: c++

Is there any way where i can access? 
There are text files like john.txt micheal.txt james.txt  ....

I can access them with this code :

```
ifstream file1( "james.txt", ios::in );
```

Can I open a file like?

```
string name = "james"; ifstream file1( name, ios::in )
```

Comment: In c++03 and earlier you'll need to use `james.c_str()`, but in principle, yes. (In C++11 it will just work.) [I'm assuming you mean to set `string name = "james.txt"`. Otherwise the `.txt` would be missing.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you can try something like:

```
ifstream file1((name + ".txt").c_str(), ios::in);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "maybe you can try"? Will it work, or not?

Comment: I said "maybe you can try" because the question was not extremely clear, and I was not sure that answered it. I am glad it did.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
char name[]="james.txt";
ifstream file1( name, ios::in );
```